# Validity of a publication record

Tags: publications

Google scholar uses statistics, such as h-index and i10-index, to encapsulate the publication performance of academics.

Is there a way to check the breakdown of an academic's research record? For example, software that shows publication breakdown into peer-reviewed journal, non-peer-reviewed journals, conference papers etc.

When an academic has hundreds of papers, it is a time consuming exercise to review. This is the motivation for this question.

Apologies if this has already been answered!

Comment: If an academic has hundreds of papers, and doesn't have a reputation - if you're an outsider, evidence for this reputation might be invited talks and the like, but it's better to just consult insiders - then I think it's safe to conclude their work isn't all that worthwhile.  And if they have a reputation - that reputation counts more than the publication record.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Scholar does not offer data about document types.

Web of Science offers good disaggregations of publication types:

First, go to a researcher profile. Then, on the right menu, click on "View Citation Reports". Here is an example of Anton Zeilinger (see bottom right):

[image]

Next, click on "Analyze Results".

You can then choose "Document Types". With our example of Anton Zeilinger, we see (out of a total 453 publications) 332 articles, 82 proceeding papers, 21 editorial materials, 14 letters, 10 book chapters, 6 notes, 6 correction etc.:

[image]